# Simple WYSIWYG editor for ASP.NET that supports images

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-controls

I need just a basic functions:

- bold text
- header text
- list (numbered)
- undo and redo
- insert image
- change background of editor

I don't need to let the user directly change html code.

There I have found some editors that supports all those functions except inserting images.
Is there some that will satisfy my needs ?

Answer (score 2):

I would look into http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried FreeTextBox?

http://www.freetextbox.com

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [CKEditor.NET](http://ckeditor.com/download).

Answer (score 0):

you can also try editor, SO uses.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43024/what-html-editor-is-used-by-stack-overflow